# Java variables casting

Tags: java, variables, casting, byte

I have a questions about casting variables in java.
I have the following code

```
    byte b1 = 6;
    byte b2 = 5;
    byte bsum;
    bsum = (b1 + b2); // (1)
```

What the code needs to be in order to work is:

```
   byte b1 = 6;
   byte b2 = 5;
   byte bsum;
   bsum = (byte)(b1 + b2); // (2)
```

Why in the (1) case eclipse says cannot convert from int to byte ? why does b1 + b2 goes to int when byte variables can take up to 127 ? I am confused..

Thanks for your time!

Comment: first thing first, read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: by default  it interpret as `int`

Comment: In java the sum of two bytes is an int because each byte could be a number (64 < x < 127), and together sum to a number greater than 127 (larger than a byte can hold). It's for the compiler's peace of mind, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) the `+` operator returns an `int` and that's why you need to do a cast.

(1) says that `b1 + b2` cannot be assigned to `byte`, because the range of the `int` is wider than the range of the `byte`.